# Powershell LDAP Request per User

Tags: powershell, ldap, user-accounts

Is there a possibility to determine when a useraccount last made an LDAP request?
I am trying to determine the User-Accounts which haven't been used for some months. I can't do this with `LastLogonDate` because a LDAP request isn't a Logon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `lastLogonTimeStamp` attributes to check inactive user/machine.
From [this page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx)

> Interactive, Network, and Service logons will update the lastLogontimeStamp. So if a user logs on interactively, browses a network share, access the email server, runs an LDAP query etc… the lastLogontimeStamp attribute will updated if the right condition is met. (The conditions are discussed below in the section Update and Replication of lastLogontimeStamp.

Comment: very informative and illuminating article thx, that helped alot!